# Please do not block this query about mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a list of mysql databases with Godaddy. I did not give them clear names now I cannot find out which website they pertain to. Can someone tell me where I can see the name of the website or domain the mysql is connected to. My fault, dumb thing to do.
Please do not get me blocked for asking a simple question.
Cheers

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a question about administering your Godaddy service. It's off-topic for SO, might be appropriate for ServerFault.com.

Comment: Your question title is really bad. It should describe the programming problem you have, not complain about SO moderating policies.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about domains hosted on GoDaddy is that you can access any of your mysql databases through any of your domains if they are all under the same account.  MySql isnt connected to any particular domain name, but rather the mysql exists on the same server and is accessible by any of your domains.  Please comment if you need further clarification, or edit your question.